# SQL Server Get all Birthday Years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that is Composed of

---

ID, B_Day

---

1, 1977-02-20

---

2, 2001-03-10

---

...

I want to add rows to this table for each year of a birthday, up to the current birthday year. 
i.e:

ID, B_Day

---

1,1977-02-20

---

1,1978-02-20

---

1,1979-02-20

---

...

---

**1,2020-02-20**

---

2, 2001-03-10

---

2, 2002-03-10

---

...

---

**2, 2019-03-10**

---

I'm struggling to determine what the best strategy for accomplishing this. I thought about recursively self-joining, but that creates far too many layers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like an odd idea. Why do you want to store each birthday?

Comment: If you have a numbers table, you could join the two tables together and use a `DATEADD(year,...` expression in the select - assuming it does the right thing so far as you're concerned for those pesky people born on Feb 29th.

Comment: By numbers do you mean years between today's date and the birthday?

Comment: Pleas edit you question you can improve question :


  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
with row_gen
  as (select top 200 row_number() over(order by name)-1 as rnk
        from master..spt_values
     )
select a.id,a.b_day,dateadd(year,rnk,b_day) incr_b_day
  from dbo.t a
  join row_gen b
    on dateadd(year,b.rnk,a.b_day)<=getdate()
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0d06c95e1914ca45ca192d0d192bd2e0

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive approach :

```
with cte as (
     select t.id, t.b_day, convert(date, getdate()) as mx_dt
     from table t
     union all
     select c.id, dateadd(year, 1, c.b_day), c.mx_dt
     from cte c
     where dateadd(year, 1, c.b_day) < c.mx_dt
)
select c.id, c.b_day
from cte c
order by c.id, c.b_day;
```

Default recursion is `100`, you can add query hint for more recursion `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: Issue with this is that someone born on Feb 29th will never have their birthday be on Feb 29th, even *in* leap years, because once it's changed to Feb 28th for their first birthday, that acts as the base date for every subsequent birthday.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is not too big, one option is to use a recursive query:

```
with cte as (
    select id, b_day bday0, b_day, 1 lvl from mytable
    union all
    select 
        id, 
        bday0, 
        dateadd(year, lvl, bday0), lvl + 1 
    from cte 
    where dateadd(year, lvl, bday0) <= getdate()
)
select id, b_day from cte order by id, b_day
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=05b28606d63b9477a8e9d6d7b7521c9a)**:

```
id | b_day     
-: | :---------
 1 | 1977-02-20
 1 | 1978-02-20
 1 | 1979-02-20
 1 | 1980-02-20
 1 | 1981-02-20
 1 | 1982-02-20
 1 | 1983-02-20
 1 | 1984-02-20
 1 | 1985-02-20
 1 | 1986-02-20
 1 | 1987-02-20
 1 | 1988-02-20
 1 | 1989-02-20
 1 | 1990-02-20
 1 | 1991-02-20
 1 | 1992-02-20
 1 | 1993-02-20
 1 | 1994-02-20
 1 | 1995-02-20
 1 | 1996-02-20
 1 | 1997-02-20
 1 | 1998-02-20
 1 | 1999-02-20
 1 | 2000-02-20
 1 | 2001-02-20
 1 | 2002-02-20
 1 | 2003-02-20
 1 | 2004-02-20
 1 | 2005-02-20
 1 | 2006-02-20
 1 | 2007-02-20
 1 | 2008-02-20
 1 | 2009-02-20
 1 | 2010-02-20
 1 | 2011-02-20
 1 | 2012-02-20
 1 | 2013-02-20
 1 | 2014-02-20
 1 | 2015-02-20
 1 | 2016-02-20
 1 | 2017-02-20
 1 | 2018-02-20
 1 | 2019-02-20
 1 | 2020-02-20
 2 | 2001-03-01
 2 | 2002-03-01
 2 | 2003-03-01
 2 | 2004-03-01
 2 | 2005-03-01
 2 | 2006-03-01
 2 | 2007-03-01
 2 | 2008-03-01
 2 | 2009-03-01
 2 | 2010-03-01
 2 | 2011-03-01
 2 | 2012-03-01
 2 | 2013-03-01
 2 | 2014-03-01
 2 | 2015-03-01
 2 | 2016-03-01
 2 | 2017-03-01
 2 | 2018-03-01
 2 | 2019-03-01
 2 | 2020-03-01
```

Comment: So someone born on '1980-02-29''s birthday in 1984 is on the 28th, not the 29th?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: ah yes that's a good point. I updated my answer to handle this use case.